# Not able to SSH in LAN

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I'm not able to do ssh to other machines in my LAN not even other machines are able to ssh to my machine (except 2 machines). My firewall service is off, network is also of the same n/w. sshd also using port 22, I've searched a lot and tried everything, but still no luck.

> Note : ssh works for public servers and 2 machines from my LAN

I have entered command SSH with o/p:

```
[KS131@localhost ~]$ ssh -vvv  KS122@192.168.1.41
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/KS131/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.41" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.41 [192.168.1.41] port 22.
```

After long time:

```
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.41 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.41 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Command iptables -L o/p:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: @drewbenn My machine is centos7, saw /var/log/secure, nothing is there after timeout

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure... what is the output of `iptables -L`?

Comment: @maulinglawns : I've added iptables -L o/p in the question.

Comment: Can you connect between systems on your LAN on other ports?  It's not unusual for Wi-Fi networks in particular to limit connection between hosts on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Do following checks to make sure the clients have permissions to ssh to your server:

1. Ensure `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` is not configured.
2. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make sure you have committed below settings.

> PermitRootLogin
>   AllowUsers
>   AllowGroups
>   DenyUsers
>   DenyGroups

3. Make sure you have upgraded to the latest ssh for both clients and your server.

Plus, you can also debug from the server side:

1. Stop sshd daemon via `/etc/init.d/sshd stop` or `systemctl stop sshd` if you are running RHEL 7+ or Ubuntu 16.04+.
2. Manually issue the sshd daemon with the `-ddd` parameter

   > /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
3. Now, try to connect from the client side, you will see verbose information on your server screen.